# How do I move a canvas on the listview?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone, uwp

I want to keep an always topmost canvas on a listview. Canvas should be stretch on window and if the user tries to scroll listview, listview must scroll but canvas must be topmost transparently and user can see listview. My XAML tree like below that:

```
 <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer>
            <ListView>
            </ListView>
        </ScrollViewer>
        <Canvas Name="DxPanel"></Canvas>
 </Grid>
```

I am trying to make a note taking app. The reqirements like that:

1. Each listview has image or richeditbox control (I have already done it)
2. The user can draw something on image or rich text
3. The listview must have infinite scroll ability and data of list view must retrieve from database and data and UI recycling must be supported.
4. The drawing layer must be endless scroll

I know this is hard challenge. I am planning to save stroke , and text data in db and image data in disk.

Comment: What's the problem with the current code?

Comment: What app are you developing? It cannot both be wpf and uwp.

Comment: Yes, you are right. This is an uwp app.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I need to say, there is no need to put a `ListView` inside a `ScrollViewer`, by default `ListView` can be scrolled if there are many items, this is because there is a `ScrollViewer` inside the template of `ListView`, you can refer to the default [ListView styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299137.aspx).

Then, if your `Canvas` keeps covering the `ListView`, there is no way for your `ListView` to get focused, let alone make the `ListView` scrolling. So I suggest you to rethink about this, why should your `Canvas` be topmost transparently?

If you want your `ListView` can be scrolled/focused, and in the meanwhile your layout in the `Canvas` can be seen, then you can put the `ListView` above the `Canvas`, by default the background of `ListView` is transparent.

You can leave a comment to tell us what is in your `Canvas`, why this `Canvas` should be stretch and placed on the top of the `ListView`, maybe we can try to find other way to solve your problem.

Comment: Hi Grace,
Thank your response. Actually, I am trying to make a more taking app. The reqirements like that:

1. Each listview has image or richeditbox control (I have already done it)
2. The user can draw something on image or rich text
3. The listview must have infinite scroll ability and data of list view must retrieve from database and data and UI recycling must be supported.
4. The drawing layer must be endless scroll

I know this is hard challenge. I am planning to save stroke , and text data in db and image data in disk.

Comment: The first three conditions are not big problem, but for "4. The drawing layer must be endless scroll I know this is hard challenge. " I suggest that after tap on one item of `ListView`, show a dialog with scrollviewer inside it, or just make a `Grid` with `Srollviewer` and `OK`, `Cancel` buttons inside it to be visible. After tapping on the `OK` button on dialog or this grid, make this layout for drawing disappear. What do you think about this workaround?